# How to get visible start and end dates in AnyGantt?

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

How can I get the visible date interval in AnyGantt? I  need to add two buttons to move back and forth the gantt, but I can't find how to do it. I was thinking on reading current start and end dates and then zooming the gantt to the new values...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to inform you that new version of AnyGantt 8.1.0 provides new methods to get max and min of visible range.
You may learn more about them and find example on [the following page](https://api.anychart.com/8.1.0/anychart.scales.GanttDateTime#getRange)

Answer (score 0):

Mendi,

In this case zooming the gantt to the new values is one of available ways to do it.
Check this example which demonstrates using html buttons and zoomTo() method to scroll timeline :
https://jsfiddle.net/Shestac92/9zzhw472/3/

```
chart.zoomTo(start, end);
```

Also you may use out-of-the-box method to add similar buttons to horizontal scroll bar, check example in Anychart Playground:
https://playground.anychart.com/api/7.14.3/core/ui/anychart.core.ui.ScrollBar.buttonsVisible-plain

```
scrollBar.buttonsVisible(true);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The first solution does not completely solve the problem. It does if I control that start and end variables never go over the limits, but if the user moves the visible area dragging the timeline with the mouse, then the buttons stop behaving correctly because start and end variables in the fiddle are not aligned with the visible interval any more. That was the reason of asking for the way to somehow read the visible start and end dates each time, so that I could add values to be able to zoomTo correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of September 2017, AnyGantt 7.14.3 doesn't provide such methods to get the visible start and end dates. We look ahead to add this feature in future releases.